# Audacity has all my audio, but blocks are repeated

Tags: audacity

I've just recorded about an hour of audio in Audacity.  All the data appears to be there, but unfortunately it's all duplicated -- it seems that blocks of roughly three seconds are repeated, and the recording is twice as long as it should be.  So if I was expecting to hear `abc` then I've actualy got `aabbcc`.

All the blocks seem to be the same length, although I've not determined that length yet, and I hypothesise that they must be bit-identical, but I've not checked that either.  I'm looking for a way to de-duplicate the audio, leaving me with something I can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your profile says you are a programmer, then you can fix this fairly easily by writing a small program that will open your WAV file, then copy n bytes, skip n bytes, etc until the end of the file. You can also prove that the repeated chunks are bit identical too.

Off the top of my head, here's the C# code I would write using my own library of audio utils  ([NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com)). There are similar libraries available for other programming languages.

```
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader("myfile.wav"))
{
    using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter("fixed.wav", reader.WaveFormat);
    {
        // buffer size is the magic number - based on sample rate, bit depth, no of channels,
        // and duration of the repeated segment,
        byte[] buffer = new byte[5000];
        int read;
        do
        {
            // read the block to copy
            read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            // read the block to discard
            read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        } while (read > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does appear to be my best bet.

Answer (score -1):

Dont know what version you have.  I am stuck with 2.1 due to old opsys.

But it sounds like you have interleaved stereo instead of the dual stereo files.  Maybe thats the other way around:)

So is it duplicated on screen in audacity or is it duplicated in the physical wav file?

Can you play the file okay or do you hear those repeats as stutter.

Really need a lot more detailed info to know what your sitrep is.

Comment: Might be worth reading the date of the OP before asking for further information. Also consider whether the answer you submit is of a higher quality than an existing accepted answer. Does it add value?